Setting labels to be the "Blocking" type using PyQGIS
I'm trying to apply the Blocking label on a layer using PyQGIS but with no success. I also would like to be able to set the obstacle weight as well.
Here is my code so far:
from qgis.core import QgsProject, QgsPalLayerSettings, QgsVectorLayerSimpleLabeling

layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('camadaPoligono')[0]
layer_settings = QgsPalLayerSettings()
layer_settings.obstacleSettings().setIsObstacle(True)
layer_settings = QgsVectorLayerSimpleLabeling(layer_settings)
layer.setLabelsEnabled(True)
layer.setLabeling(layer_settings)
layer.triggerRepaint()


You can use/adapt the snippet below. I found it necessary to set the label settings drawLabels attribute to False, since the layer features are only acting as obstacles.
To set the obstacle weight, use the QgsLabelObstacleSettings.setFactor method, passing a float value between 0.0 & 2.0.
When setting obstacle settings on a polygon layer, you should also set the ObstacleType.
from qgis.core import QgsProject, QgsPalLayerSettings, QgsLabelObstacleSettings, QgsVectorLayerSimpleLabeling
from qgis.utils import iface


layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('camadaPoligono')[0]
lbl_settings = QgsPalLayerSettings()
ob_settings = QgsLabelObstacleSettings()
ob_settings.setIsObstacle(True)
ob_settings.setFactor(2.0)# Float value between 0.0 & 2.0
ob_settings.setType(QgsLabelObstacleSettings.ObstacleType.PolygonInterior)
lbl_settings.setObstacleSettings(ob_settings)
lbl_settings.drawLabels = False
lyr_labeling = QgsVectorLayerSimpleLabeling(lbl_settings)

layer.setLabeling(lyr_labeling)
layer.setLabelsEnabled(True)
iface.mapCanvas().refresh()

